# Can't setup Compass with WebStorm

Tags: css, webstorm, compass-sass, compass

I'm trying to setup Compass in a pre-existing WebStorm project, however the css files are not linking correctly. I have tired changing the relative links, but have not had any luck.

I generated the folders and `config.rb` by running `compass init`. Ideally, I would want these folders moved so they are all under `public` (ie sass, stylesheets etc)

I am including them in `layout.jade` with

```
 link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/screen.css'
    media="screen, projection" type="text/css" )
```

See screenshot:

//Removed because I cant post that many links

I am not getting any errors, the styles just aren't applying to the page.

**Edit:**

I'm very confused - the css under stylesheets looks correct, but the css under the scss files has the error ' File to import not found or unreadable: compass/reset. on line 6 of screen.scss'. Why are there two css files?:

[image: css files]

**Edit 3:**

The error seems to be here, but I cannot figure out how to fix it?

[image: screen.css error]

Comment: where is the generated css saved?

Comment: Well your screen.css is not in your stylesheet map, according to your picture. That's why it isn't working

Comment: Based on screenshot .. it looks like generated `.css` file gets saved next to the source file in the same `sass` folder instead of `stylesheets`

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue:

Because of:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

in app.js,  the jade code in layout.jade was compiling from:

```
layout.jade

href='/stylesheets/screen.css'
```

into:

```
index.html

href='/public/stylesheets/screen.css'
```

Moving the stylesheets etc folders be under public and updating config.rb fixed it.

config.rb:

```
css_dir = "/public/stylesheets"
sass_dir = "/public/sass"
images_dir = "/public/images"
javascripts_dir = "/public/javascripts"
```